# Producer Consumer with BlockingQueues in Java EE as background task

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, producer-consumer

I want to implement a **producer consumer pattern as a background task in my web app**.
**I need to start/stop scheduled bets and do related tasks (List the transactions and other things) in my web app automatically.**

This will be running 24/7 (and will block/stop when nothing is produced ?).

Here is an implementation using the new EJB async methods (so no need to use a thread pool and creating tasks as classes)

Is this a proper solution ? Implementing a bean that I can manage for example in the admin panel and start and stop the monitoring when I want.

```
@Singleton
@Stateless
@ManagedBean
public class BetManagerBean{

    private BlockingQueue nonStartedBetsQueue_ = new ...;
    private BlockingQueue startedBetsQueue_ = new ...;
    private BlockingQueue finishedBetsQueue_ = new ...;
    private boolean monitoring_ = false;
    private int delay_ = 10000;

    @Inject
    BetDao betDao;


    public boolean getMonitoring(){
        return monitoring_;
    }
    public void setMonitoring(boolean monitoring){
        monitoring_ = monitoring;
    }


    public void startMonitoring(){
        if(monitoring_ == false){
            setMonitoring(true);
            fetchesNonStartedBets();
            monitorNonStartedBets();
            monitorStartedBets();
            monitorFinishedBets();
        }
    }

    public void stopMonitoring(){
        setMonitoring(false);
    }

    @Async
    private void fetchesNonStartedBets(){
        while(monitoring_){
            List<BetEntity> nonStartedBets = betDao.getNonStartedBets();
            for(BetEntity bet : nonStartedBets){
                nonStartedBetsQueue_.put(bet);
            }
            Thread.getCurrentThread.sleep(delay_);
        }
    }

    @Async
    private void monitorNonStartedBets(){
        while(monitoring_){
            BetEntity bet = nonStartedBetsQueue_.take();    
            if(checkBetStart(bet)){
                betsToRemove.add(bet);
                bet = initiateBet(bet);
                startedBetQueue_.put(bet);
                betDao.updateBet(bet);
            }
            else{
                nonStartedBetsQueue_.put(bet); //Reput it in the queue
            }
        }
    }

    @Async
    private void monitorStartedBets(){
        while(monitoring_){
            BetEntity bet = startedBetsQueue_.take();
            bet = updateBet(bet);
            if(checkBetFinish(bet)){
                bet = closeBet(bet);
                finishedBetsQueue_.put(bet);
                betDao.updateBet(bet);
            }
            else{
                 startedBetsQueue_.put(bet); //Reput it in the queue
            }
        }
    }

    @Async
    private void monitorFinishedBets(){
        while(monitoring_){
            BetEntity bet = finishedBetsQueue_.take();
            manageBet(bet); //do some stuff....
        }
    }


}
```

I'm waiting for your comments or suggestions, feel free to correct me on anything you want.

Thank you !

Comment: I already read about the new ManagedExecutor and the Async Bean. But this does not solve my problem ( or maybe I just don't see how ) because my threads are 3 constantly running threads, and not just some tasks that I want to do asynchronously.

Comment: If you are using threads to represent state, your design is most probably wrong.  
Just use a DB; it will make everything so much easier.

Comment: The thread does'nt represent the state, but does some task for my objects that are in the particular state.

I'm doing this because I don't have the control over the data, I can just read it and THEN do something.